# How can I check if a loaded Python function changed?

Tags: python

As a data scientist / machine learning developer, I have most of the time (always?) a `load_data` function. Executing this function often takes more than 5 minutes, because the executed operations are expensive. When I store the end result of `load_data` in a pickle file and read that file again, then the time often goes down to a few seconds.

So a solution I use quite often is:

```
def load_data(serialize_pickle_path, original_filepath):
    invalid_hash = True

    if os.path.exists(serialize_pickle_path):
        content = mpu.io.read(serialize_pickle_path)
        data = content['data']
        invalid_hash = mpu.io.hash(original_filepath) != content['hash']

    if invalid_hash:
        data = load_data_initial()
        filehash = mpu.io.hash(original_filepath)
        mpu.io.write(serialize_pickle_path, {'data': data, 'hash': filehash})

    return data
```

This solution has a major drawback: If the `load_data_initial` changed, the file will not be reloaded.

**Is there a way to check for changes in Python functions?**

Comment: What do you mean by "changed"? You mean someone edited the source code between the last time you quit the program and the next time you start it?

Comment: Well, you (the developer) are the only one who can know whether the result of `load_data_initial` has changed. You need to implement that logic somewhere. Python cannot know that without calling the function again (which you have if you remove all of the caching).

Comment: @abarnert Exactly. And that someone is most of the time myself. This question is NOT about security.

Comment: I've added an answer to give you some ideas, but you might want to consider a different approach: changing your workflow. Hopefully you're using some kind of version control software, like git? If so, why not just (a) add a script that wipes out your cached pickles, then (b) add a commit hook that, whenever you change the relevant module, runs that script? (You can always use the no-hook flag if you occasionally need to change the module without regenerating your pickles—worst-case scenario, you forget once every week or two and lose 5 minutes…)

Comment: @zvone As abarnert posted an answer that does exactly what I was looking for, I think your proven wrong.

Comment: @abarnert Oh, that sounds nice! Could you please add some details about such a hook in your answer?

Comment: @MartinThoma OK; give me a few minutes.

Comment: @MartinThoma What? You question is unclear and was clarified in the comments. I'm one of the guys who invested time in reading your question and commenting on it and you are now trying to achieve what exactly with this comment?

Comment: @zvone If your comment is simply wrong, you should delete it. Saying something is not possible when it is, is harmful. If I just didn't see what you mean, it would be nice if you could clarify the aspect I missed.

Comment: @MartinThoma I wrote it was impossible to know whether the *"result of load_data_initial has changed"* without implementing the logic behind that yourself. We are talking about a function which is not present in the question at all. What I wrote is not wrong! What your question is not asking is how to know whether the *code* of the function changed. You got an answer for that, but that answers only the question you had in your mind and not the one you wrote here.

Comment: @zvone I don't see your point. Where is the difference beween the function and the code of the function? I would say the code of a function fully defines the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're asking whether there's a way to tell whether someone changed the source code of the function between the last time you quit the program and the next time you start it…

There's no way to do this directly, but it's not that hard to do manually, if you don't mind getting a little hacky.

Since you've `import`ed the module and have access to the function, you can use the [`getsource`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource) function to get its source code. So, all you need to do is save that source. For example:

```
def source_match(source_path, object):
    try:
        with open(source_path) as f:
            source = f.read()
        if source == inspect.getsource(object):
            return True
    except Exception as e:
        # Maybe log e or something here, but any of the obvious problems,
        # like the file not existing or the function not being inspectable,
        # mean we have to re-generate the data
        pass
    return False

def load_data(serialize_pickle_path, original_filepath):
    invalid_hash = True
    if os.path.exists(serialize_pickle_path):
        if source_match(serialize_pickle_path + '.sourcepy', load_data_initial):
            content = mpu.io.read(serialize_pickle_path)
            data = content['data']
            invalid_hash = mpu.io.hash(original_filepath) != content['hash']
    # etc., but make sure to save the source when you save the pickle too
```

---

Of course even if the body of the function hasn't changed, its effect might change because of, e.g., a change in some module constant, or the implementation of some other function it uses. Depending on how much this matters, you could pull in the entire module it's defined in, or that module plus every other module that it recursively depends on, etc.

And of course you can also save hashes of text instead of the full text, to make things a little smaller. Or embed them in the pickle file instead of saving them alongside.

Also, if the source isn't available because it comes from an module you only distribute in `.pyc` format, you obviously can't check the source. You could pickle the function, or just access its `__code__` attribute. But if the function comes from a C extension module, even that won't work. At that point, the best you can do is check the timestamp or hash of the whole binary file.

And plenty of other variations. But this should be enough to get you started.

---

A completely different alternative is to do the checking as part of your development workflow, instead of as part of the program.

Assuming you're using some kind of version control (if not, you really should be), most of them come with some kind of commit hook system. For example, `git` comes with [a whole slew of options](https://githooks.com/). For example, if you have a program named `.git/hooks/pre-commit`, it will get run every time you try to `git commit`.

Anyway, the simplest pre-commit hook would be something like (untested):

```
#!/bin/sh
git diff --name-only | grep module_with_load_function.py && python /path/to/pickle/cleanup/script.py
```

Now, every time you do a `git commit`, if the diffs include any change to a file named `module_with_load_function.py` (obviously use the name of the file with `load_data_initial` in it), it will first run the script `/path/to/pickle/cleanup/script.py` (which is a script you write that just deletes all the cached pickle files).

If you've edited the file but know you don't need to clean out the pickles, you can just `git commit --no-verify`. Or you can expand on the script to have an environment variable that you can use to skip the cleaning, or to only clean certain directories, or whatever you want. (It's probably better to default to cleaning overzealously—worst-case scenario, when you forget every few weeks, you waste 5 minutes waiting, which isn't as bad as waiting 3 hours for it to run a bunch of processing on incorrect data, right?)

You can expand on this to, e.g., check the complete diffs and see if they include the function, instead of just checking the filenames. The hooks are just anything executable, so you can write them in Python instead of bash if they get too complicated.

If you don't know `git` all that well (or even if you do), you'll probably be happier installing a third-party library like [`pre-commit`](https://pre-commit.com/) that makes it easier to manage hooks, write them in Python (without having to deal with complicated `git` commands), etc. If you *are* comfortable with `git`, just looking at [`hooks--pre-commit.sample`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/templates/hooks--pre-commit.sample) and some of the other samples in the `templates` directory should be enough to give you ideas.